# Magento 2 Cloud: turn on developer mode

Tags: magento2, deploy, magento-cloud

I need to turn on developer mode, but **NOT** via the following command:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

I need to turn it on via **deploy**.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: As I know this is impossible in case you don't have full permission to file system. I recommend to create a ticket to Cloud team with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Login to Magento Cloud via **SSH**

**Example**:-

```
ssh 1.ent-basant-production-south1@ssh.us-3.magento.cloud
```

& Run

```
nano app/etc/env.php
```

& Add the Following or Update the following on **app/etc/env.php** File. This file has write access & can be updated using SSH.

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'
```

Press `Ctrl + z + Y` to save the file

[image]

Now run

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Now you can check the mode using

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

You'll find Developer mode is active.

> Please note :- It is always advisable to change the following file
> locally and use

```
git push origin <environment>
```

> to update it in Cloud Environment, Automatically Triggering Deploy,
> Not to edit the file directly using SSH.